# in Angular, $document.find('body').eq(0) vs $document[0].body

Tags: angularjs, document

In Angularjs is there any significant difference between these two methods? I tend to use them both interchangeably.

`$document.find('body').eq(0)` vs `$document[0].body`

Comment: One thing I'm noticing is that $document.find('body').eq(0) returns and angular element, but $document[0].body does not. so to use the second option one needs to wrap it in angular.element().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.find` has to go out and search through all the children for an element of type `body`. But the `body` element is stored directly on the `document`. So, for `body` it is much more efficient to grab it off of the `document`.